# php web spider. how to identify url with hash as same page?

Tags: php, web-crawler, redirect

I have a function:

```
public function getHeaders($url){
        $ch = curl_init();

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,            $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER,         true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY,         true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,        10);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false);
        $x = curl_exec($ch);

        curl_close($ch);
        return (array) HTTP::parse_header_string($x) ;
    }
```

When `$url=http://www.google.com', i have header location:`http://www.google.de/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=SOMEHASHGOESHERE`
load it again and get all same but, 'SOMEHASHGOESHERE' is other now.

My task is to develop web-crawler. I know how to do basic logic of it. But there are few nuances. One of them are: What must do my spider if requested url send to it header 'location' and try to redirect? What model of behavior must control my spider to be impossible drop it into infinite redirect loop?

(how to identify similar urls like http://www.google.de/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=SOMEHASHGOESHERE which usually are using for loop redirection and give to my spider understanding to ignore such links )

Comment: I don't follow. Are you seeking a google-specific answer or a general one?

Comment: Since you seem to be after a general solution, what's wrong with setting `CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS`?

Comment: Nothing wrong, I just saw about it few hours ago. Thanks, but I already solved with my function with recursive limit of calls))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to just process the target of all redirections you can get curl to follow url's without returning redirection page.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
```

if you are just interested in the base url without url parameters you can get it easily with explode:

```
$urlParts = explode("?",$url);
$baseUrl = $urlParts[0];
```

Comment: I think it's bad idea. What will happen when spider will analyse some specific site which have some specific link what will generate loop redirects? I think to count redirects and break when redirect count is more than 5 for example.. But it also interest to see other solutions.

Comment: if you could explain your problem more thoroughly, i can answer.

Comment: Okay, Il'l try. My answer is edited.
P.S. Sorry for bad english